# ES6 arrow function within forEach() not working

Tags: javascript, express, foreach, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a chatbot for the Facebook Messenger Platform and I discovered a problem which is driving me crazy because I can't figure out **why** it is a problem.

This code is working.

```
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {

   let body = req.body;

   // Checks this is an event from a page subscription
   if (body.object === 'page') {

       // Iterates over each entry
       body.entry.forEach(function(entry) {

           // Gets the body of the webhook event
           let webhookEvent = entry.messaging[0];
           console.log(webhookEvent);

       });

       res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');
   }
   else {
       // Returns a '404 Not Found'
       res.sendStatus(404);
   }

});
```

But initially, I wanted to have this `function(entry)` within the `forEach` to be an **ES6 arrow function**, like:

```
body.entry.forEach((entry) => {

   // Gets the body of the webhook event
   let webhookEvent = entry.messaging[0];
   console.log(webhookEvent);
});
```

But the **logs in the console** are pointing out this:

```
at body.entry.forEach (/app/src/app.js:57:41)
2017-12-19T15:10:08.768620+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
2017-12-19T15:10:08.768631+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
2017-12-19T15:10:08.768632+00:00 app[web.1]:     at app.post (/app/src/app.js:54:17)
2017-12-19T15:10:08.768634+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2017-12-19T15:10:08.768636+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2017-12-19T15:10:08.768637+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2017-12-19T15:10:08.768638+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2017-12-19T15:10:08.768638+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2017-12-19T15:10:08.768639+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2017-12-19T15:10:08.768640+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Why is this not working with ES6 arrow functions?

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: I don't think problem is with arrow function, please check if `entry`  contains `messaging` and `messaging` has data inside it.

Comment: Did you make sure that `body.entry` is an array?

Comment: entry definitely contains messaging

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: Good idea with the node version. I hosted the app on heroku and a quick research revealed that I need to specify the Node-version within my package.json. Will do this now!

Comment: I specified the Node-version within my package.json and so far I wasn't able to produce this problem again.
I will check it for a while and then I will answer this question here.
Thank you guys so far!
BTW: I'm using Node 8.9.3